# AngularJS: XHR returning net::ERR_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED error to PUT/POST requests

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue processing responses from a server to a PUT request (same happens with POST). Starts with the following CORS pre-flight request.

Request:

```
OPTIONS /open/Patient/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: remoteserver.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://myclient
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myclient/patient/2JT
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 13 Sep 2014 16:58:28 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Location, Location
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Server: Name of remote server
```

Then the actual request:

```
PUT /open/Patient/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: remoteserver.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 775
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json+fhir, application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://myclient
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json+fhir
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myclient/patient/2JT
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The response is not processed by AngularJS, instead it reports the following error:

net::ERR_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED

The body of the response is empty, and the status is "0". Thing is, if I set a break point in the Chrome debugger, after stepping through the code, I DO get a successful response. Here's what I get in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json+fhir; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 154
Date: Sat, 13 Sep 2014 17:13:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Location, Location
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Location: http://remoteserver/open/Patient/1/_history/6
Server: Health Intersections FHIR Server
```

Here's the body of my code that sends the request using $http:

```
function updateResource(resourceUrl, resource) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.put(resourceUrl, resource)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var results = {};
            results.data = data;
            results.headers = headers();
            results.status = status;
            results.config = config;
            deferred.resolve(results);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            var error = { "status": status, "outcome": data };
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I've resolved this issue working with the developer of the server. Turns out there was an issue with the way the server handled connections. Resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue working with the developer of the server. Turns out there was an issue with the way the server handled connections. Resolved.